# when i click button of child component to open winBox it only open once

Tags: javascript, web, svelte, sveltekit

I'm new to svelte (sveltekit) and im making win95 style portfolio.
when using [this](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/svelte-winbox) svelte wrapper for winbox.js .
everything is working fine except when i click on folder button it opens winbox once after that it isnt working.
i have no idea what's the problem.

here's my code for component.

```
<script>
  export let name = "Folder";
  export let icon = "/icons/folder.png";
  export let cls = "";
  import { WinBox } from "svelte-winbox";
  let openProfile;
</script>

<button
  on:click={() => {
    console.log("clicked");
  }}
  tabindex="0"
  class="group text-center w-folder  {cls}"
>
  <img class=" inline" src={icon} alt={name} height="40" width="40" />
  <p
    class="group-focus:outline-dotted 
    group-focus:outline-1
    group-focus:bg-blue
    text-xs text-white mt-2"
  >
    {name}
  </p>
</button>
<WinBox
  bind:createWindow={openProfile}
  onclose={() => {
    console.log("closed");
  }}
>
  <slot />
</WinBox>
```

parent.svelte

```
<script>
  import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte";

  import Folder from "../lib/elements/Folder.svelte";
  const computer_user_icon = "/icons/computer-user.png";
  const work_dir = "/icons/directory_open_file_mydocs-4.png";
</script>

<div class="flex gap-5 p-4 flex-col">
  <Folder name="Profile" icon={computer_user_icon}>
    <h2 class="text-2xl font-bold text-dark text-center">Hello!</h2>
    <p>This is a box. It can contain anything.</p>
  </Folder>
  <Folder name="Work" icon={work_dir} />
</div>
```

Comment: It seems you're not calling `openProfile` anywhere here?

Comment: i do in parent section

Comment: no you are not, nowhere in the code you posted do you have anywhere `openProfile = ...`,

Comment: i dont have to , check the package link i have attached to question.